# JSON object reply parsing

Tags: javascript, json, class, parsing, object

So when the Ajax call returns a JSON reply, I do :

```
oData = JSON.parse(sReply);
```

where

```
var oData = new cData();

function cData() {
    this.Email = "";
    this.Name = "";
    this.test = function () {
        alert("lol");
    }
}
```

The problem is, the JSON string only contains the email and the name variables, so when the oData = JSON.parse(sReply) happens, the function test gets overwritten and when I try to call the function it does not exist. Is there a way to avoid this? I may have many functions in there and other variables which I don't want to transmit through JSON.

Comment: can you post the JSON value and what the desired output is for the oData object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`oData = JSON.parse(sReply);` - This creates a JavaScript object. It doesn't matter if oData was previously a `cData` object...you just re-assigned it.

You should be able to take your JSON response and manually assign its properties to an existing `cData` object:

```
var oData = new cData();
var response = JSON.parse(sReply);
oData.Email = response.Email;
oData.Name = response.Name;
```

Or you could loop through the properties:

```
for (var i in response)
    oData[i] = response[i];
```

Comment: Thanks alot! that's what i did, parsed the reply to the response and then with an oData.init function just assigned the corresponding variables. I thought that I would have to declare response as the simplified version of the oData ( without the function ) but it was needed!

Answer (score 3):

JSON has no provisions for encoding functions. It's only for data.

You can serialize the functions as strings from JavaScript, of course, and similarly reconstitute them, but that won't work too well in other languages. (What would your Python code do with a JavaScript function?)

If you think about the general problem of data interchange, particularly when it involves services from incompletely-trusted providers, the idea of allowing functions through the data encoding gets pretty scary.

Comment: i don't want js code in python. the oData is a javascript object which manipulates the user data with functions, like the test() function. i just use the json to populate the intended variables of the object

Answer (score 2):

A common way to solve this problem is to provide your Object (`cData`) with a static [factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) which will accept the DTO ([Data Transfer Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)) and return a new `cData` instance, ie:

```
function cData() { 
    this.Email = "";
    this.Name = "";
    this.test = function () {
        alert("lol");
    }
}

// Static factory which produces a new `cData` object from the supplied
// Data Transfer Object.  Note this function belongs to the Constructor
// function rather than instances created when it's used.
cData.fromDTO(value) {
        // Create a new cData instance.
        var result = new cData();

        // Copy the properties from the DTO.
        result.Email = value.Email;
        result.Name = value.Name;

        // Return the populated instance.
        return result;
}
```

You can then make use of the static factory to handle the result of the AJAX call, ie:

```
function onAjaxResponse(response) {
    var myData = cData.fromDTO(JSON.parse(response));

    // Invoke the 'test' method.
    myData.test();
}
```

This also provides a clear seperation between the Data Transport layer (data coming from the server) and your business logic (your JavaScript application); if you need to change a property of the DTO (eg: `Name` changes to `FirstName`) then you only have to modify the code in one place (the `fromDTO` factory method).

As a side note, you should consider [making use of BumpyCaps when naming Constructor Functions](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) (ie: the first character should be upper case, ie: `MyClass` instead of `myClass` as you would any other function).

Comment: Very interesting method, thank you, though it seems kind of an overkill. I went along with just doing response = JSON.parse(reply) and then oData.Email = response.Email ( within an oData init function which accepts as parameter the response variable )

Comment: Yep, that's a valid solution as well - I would say that my approach benefits from separating object construction from the business logic (ie: now all instances of cData carry an init() method which they don't need to do their work).  Although it's in Java, [Misko Hevery's article](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/07/08/how-to-think-about-the-new-operator/) might prove interesting further reading on the subject.